# i can't reach the new url after defined the view function and write the url and adding some data

Tags: django

strong texti was creating a new URL route after write the view function and creating the template and adding some data to use it and i still can't reach my URL

views.py

```
    def new_topic(request, pk):
        board = get_object_or_404(Board, pk=pk)7
        return render(request, 'new_topic.html', {'board': board})
```

urls.py

```
     urlpatterns = [
            url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
            url(r'^boards/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.board_topics, name='board_topics'),
            url(r'^boards/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.new_topic, name='new_topic'),
            url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        ]
```

new_topic.html

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}

    {% block title %}Start a New Topic{% endblock %}

    {% block breadcrumb %}
      <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Boards</a></li>
      <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'board_topics' board.pk %}">{{ board.name }}</a></li>
      <li class="breadcrumb-item active">New topic</li>
    {% endblock %}

    {% block content %}

    {% endblock %}
```

I expected when i write in the `url` `that : 127.0.0.1:888/boards/3/new/`
i see what i wrote in new_topic template but it show me this error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    `http`://127.0.0.1:8000/boards/4/new
Using the `URLconf` defined in `myproject`.`urls`, `Django` tried these URL patterns, in this order:
```

```
    ^$ [name='home']
    ^boards/(?P<pk>\d+)/$ [name='board_topics']
    ^boards/(?P<pk>\d+)/$ [name='new_topic']
    ^admin/
```

The current path, boards/4/new, didn't match any of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of your urls match the incoming path, you need to create a url (and a matching view) for this path

```
url(r'^boards/(?P<pk>\d+)/new/$', views.new_board, name='board_new'),
```

Both `board_topics` and `new_topic` urls match the same path. When Django resolves the incoming request path it loops over your url definitions in order and returns the **first** match, since the `board_topics` url matches the same pattern as `new_topic`, `new_topic` will never be matched

```
url(r'^boards/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.board_topics, name='board_topics'),
url(r'^boards/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.new_topic, name='new_topic'),  # Same regex
```

Answer (score 1):

You have tried to reach path `boards/(?P<pk>\d+)/new/` but none of your URL patterns matches it. You should change the URL path for `new_topic` from `url(r'^boards/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.new_topic, name='new_topic'),` to `url(r'^boards/(?P<pk>\d+)/new/$', views.new_topic, name='new_topic'),`